# how to extract json data in xlxs using json_to_sheet

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

I am trying to fill an excel file using the JSON below. I am getting the JSON data from HTTP response and I would like to use it for downloading an excel file.

```
   {  
       "dynaModel":[  
          {  
             "map":{  
                "UNIT/SUBUNIT":"sdasd",
                "SUBUNIT/ISU/GEO":"sasd",
                "REVENUEINR-RS":"₹87,sdd",
                "COSTINR-RS":"₹47,33",
                "GMINR-RSUSD-$":46,
                "REVENUEINR-RS":"₹87,64,",
                "COSTINR-RS":"₹47,33,",
                "GMINR-RSUSD-$":46
             }
          },
          {  
             "map":{  
                "UNIT/SUBUNIT":"fghf",
                "SUBUNIT/ISU/GEO":"CMghhfI",
                "REVENUEINR-RS":"₹59,06",


          "COSTINR-RS":"₹30,43",
            "GMINR-RSUSD-$":48.47,
            "REVENUEINR-RS":"₹59",
            "COSTINR-RS":"₹30,43",
            "GMINR-RSUSD-$":48.47
         }
      },
      {  
         "map":{  
            "UNIT/SUBUNIT":"hfgh",
            "SUBUNIT/ISU/GEO":"fghh",
            "'APR-16'_REVENUEINR-RS":"₹29,72",
            "'APR-16'_COSTINR-RS":"₹11,43",
            "'APR-16'_GMINR-RSUSD-$":61.53,
            "'Total'_REVENUEINR-RS":"₹29,72",
            "'Total'_COSTINR-RS":"₹11,43",
            "'Total'_GMINR-RSUSD-$":61.53
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

my components code is shown below :

```
excelDownload(){
   this._isuGeoSubunitReportService.excelDownload(this.isugeosubunitTO)
    .subscribe(data =>this.responseStatus = data,
        err => console.log(err),
       () => console.log('Request Completed222')
    );



const ws_name = 'SomeSheet';  
const wb: WorkBook = { SheetNames: [], Sheets: {} };
const ws: any = utils.json_to_sheet(this.responseStatus.dynamoModel);
wb.SheetNames.push(ws_name);
wb.Sheets[ws_name] = ws;
const wbout = write(wb, { bookType: 'xlsx', bookSST: true, type: 'binary' });

function s2ab(s) {
  const buf = new ArrayBuffer(s.length);
  const view = new Uint8Array(buf);
  for (let i = 0; i !== s.length; ++i) {
    view[i] = s.charCodeAt(i) & 0xFF;
  };
  return buf;
}

saveAs(new Blob([s2ab(wbout)], { type: 'application/octet-stream' }), 'exported.xlsx');
}
```

I am trying to download the result in `xlxs` for which I am using `xlxs` module of json. its works fine for simple json but my json data is different.

```
   const ws: any = utils.json_to_sheet(this.responseStatus);
```

if I simply put the `this.responseStatus` it return only one `map` value in the `xlxs`.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Could you give an example of how your excel file should look like?

Answer (score 1):

There is a typing error in your code. You are using: `this.responseStatus.dynamoModel` instead of `this.responseStatus.dynaModel`.

Also, according to the [documentation](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx) of the module `xlsx`, your array to parse is expected to have a syntax like this one before using `utils.json_to_sheet`:

```js
[
  {S:1,h:2,e:3,e_1:4,t:5,J:6,S_1:7},
  {S:2,h:3,e:4,e_1:5,t:6,J:7,S_1:8}
]
```

So you can use the function `utils.aoa_to_sheet` instead of `utils.json_to_sheet`

Another option, you could create your own function that will parse your data so as to have a form like the one given in the documentation for `utils.json_to_sheet`. This is how I transformed the code in your component.

```js
excelDownload() {
    this.appService.excelDownload()
      .subscribe(data => {
          this.responseStatus = data;
          this.generateExcelFile(data);
        },
        err => console.log(err),
        () => console.log('Request Completed222')
      );
  }
  generateExcelFile(data: any) {
    this.responseStatus = data;
    const ws_name = 'SomeSheet';
    const wb: WorkBook = { SheetNames: [], Sheets: {} };
      const ws: any = utils.json_to_sheet(parseArray(this.responseStatus.dynaModel));
    wb.SheetNames.push(ws_name);
    wb.Sheets[ws_name] = ws;
    const wbout = write(wb, { bookType: 'xlsx', bookSST: true, type: 'binary' });

    function s2ab(s) {
      const buf = new ArrayBuffer(s.length);
      const view = new Uint8Array(buf);
      for (let i = 0; i !== s.length; ++i) {
        view[i] = s.charCodeAt(i) & 0xFF;
      }
      return buf;
    }
    // function to parse your array coming from the backend 
    function parseArray(dataToParse: any) {
      const newArray = [];
      dataToParse.forEach(item => {
        Object.keys(item).forEach(key => {
          newArray.push(item[key]);
        });
      });
      console.log('newArray:' + JSON.stringify(newArray));
      return newArray;
    }

    FileSaver.saveAs(new Blob([s2ab(wbout)],
      { type: 'application/octet-stream'}),
      'exported.xlsx');
  }
```